# Symbol for carriage return in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, carriage-return, line-endings

I'm writing an article about line-endings, and I can't seem to find the symbol that Eclipse uses for carriage returns when the "show whitespace" option is turned on. Can anyone help me out? Bonus virtual high five if you can also tell me the name of the symbol, as well as name and symbol for line-feeds.

Note: I'm NOT looking for how to put carriage returns in strings or anything similar, just the symbol that Eclipse uses to denote carriage returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through the link that Boann provided, I found the symbol in question.

¤ - the [Currency Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography))

I feel it would be wrong accepting that answer though, as it didn't actually answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the [pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) (¶). It dates from medieval times and is not Eclipse-specific.

Comment: That's the LF, yes? Thanks.:) I specified Eclipse because of the different notations of CR in other editors: e.g. the black CR brick in Notepad++ or ^M in vim. Also, the pilcrow looks a bit different in Eclipse, but I assume that's just the font.

Comment: @Cako I hadn't realized in the question that you were asking about the CR and LF separately. I just read both terms in the general sense of "line break". My file had Linux line-endings, so all I saw was the pilcrow, but the CR symbol it uses is the currency sign, yes.